# How to revert a do-release-upgrade?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I can update my Ubuntu to the new LTS version. As you can think, its not a highly important server since I run 13.10 (not a LTS version). Anyway - I actually want to upgrade my server, but would like to be able to revert this upgrade.

I would be able to reinstall Ubuntu 13.10 and overwrite it with my backup. But I want to know if there is a more comfortable way to do this. TBH I guess theres no command as `undo-release-upgrade` but I thought it would be worth to ask for it.

This is my current daily backup script

```
tar cvpzf $backup_file --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=$backup_file --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys --exclude=/media --exclude=/tmp /
```

Comment: If you're using LVM or btrfs, you could take snapshots. But really, upgrades are one-way... You need a test environment (could be as simple as a VM somewhere) so you can test upgrading.

Comment: Debian does not support downgrades, and therefore Ubuntu does not either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Faheem said [in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450906/best-way-to-undo-a-release-upgrade#comment592191_450906), **you can't revert/downgrade the version of Ubuntu** once you upgrade it. The only possibility is to do an image of the system, or complete backup and then installing it over. You can also test in a VM as derobert suggest.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use Clonzilla to backup the disk/partition. Then just restore the created image to go back to your previous config if something is wrong with 14.04.
Best